# Data structure for songs in Android

Tags: java, android, data-structures, collections

Basically I am creating an android music player. I have managed to store a STRING into the "comment" section of each song in my library.

The String is of form eg. "guitar, drums, spanish, sad"

Now my concerns is to come up with a data structure to move around this mp3 file (its path) along with this STRING, in my code. What makes it more challenging is that:

the String as u saw above is made up of commas "," So every time a user wants to create a playlist, they will just give me a list of words (TAGS) and I have to look into every song to find if it has the TAG they are looking for or not. I do so by splitting the String stored in the COMMENT section of the song into sub-strings(TAGS) and match it when the users input.

I am looking for suggestion for a good data structure.

Should I split the COMMENT Section before hand and keep it in some sort of collection? or do it as I am looping through every song ? split it to check it against the inputs?

I thought of using ArrayList >
but maybe there is a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reverse index will be more suitable if the list of songs is long. That is instead of looping through each song and checking if contains the tag you can find the tag directly and extract list of songs associated with it. Jumping to a tag directly can be done by using a Map and within an entry the value could be a List of Song(s).

```
Map<String, List<Song>> tagIndex
```

I am assuming Song is a class that abstracts a song.

If its not possible to persist the index it can be built at startup in background.

**EDIT-1**: (reply to first comment)

I think all Android devices have SQLite available. If this is indeed the case an easy to integrate then there are couple of ways you can store and access the tags.

1. Store tags in database and comments.
2. Store tags in database only.

In the first approach tags will survive application re-installs. But then comments are accessible for other applications too which may use it in other ways or edit/overwrite your values. In this approach you'll have to build the index at application install and keep the comments and database in sync on the go once the initial index is built.

Second approach is partly similar to first where tags stored in database and maintained on the go. But there is no initial build and tags may get erased if application is un-installed. This may or may not be acceptable but this approach is simpler than the first.

If SQLite is used you'll not need to maintain tags in memory at all. Everything can be maintained in database.

> Table: tag_index
>
> Columns: (tag_name, song_name, song_path)

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, I will accept this as an answer, as soon as I can wrap my head around it. Because I would still need to find some how every unique TAG to map all the songs to it right ? Again by going through every song TAG and see if it exist or not ?

Comment: Please see EDIT-1. Didn't have enough chars in comment.

Comment: By couple of ways you mean SQLite and Map<String, String>... just had a quick look at SQLite, I think its command line and using it through phones interface will be difficult isn't it ?

Comment: Android provides an API to SQLite. The API looks simple in the following link.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#overview_sqliteandroid

Comment: This is really helpful, just one question in the 1st approach, what do u mean by "store tags in db and comments", Because if a comment section is split into sub-strings it makes tags, where each song will contain different tags (as one long comment/string) So comment is tag is kind of the same

Comment: In first approach, as and when user creates tags you'll have to first append the tag to song's comment and then also insert an entry in database.

Appending tags to comments will only be useful in case of application re-installs. AFAIK the database gets deleted when application is removed. So when its installed again the old tags can be retained. Apart from this scenario accessing comments will never be needed.

Whereas the database will be accessed most of the time for querying songs with tags input by user.

Answer (score 1):

Arraylist is the way to good in my opinion, since you will have a list of different TAGS i suppose.

But i would suggest not using a string as the type, perhaps you should use a list of a tag class which will give you more flexibility in the future when you need to make changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ryan, I can only store a string value into the COMMENT section of every song, but of course every time I retrieve it, I split it into a list of sub-strings(Tags)

Comment: Exactly, so what's the matter if you can split it into sub_string?

Comment: You can use stringTokenizer for breaking up tags (old school way)

Comment: should I do it in advance ? or when the user wants to create a playlist by entering a few TAGs he wants his playlist to have, The system go through every song, split it into list of TAGs, check if the song has the tag the user is after else move to the next song...loop the whole library.

Comment: Ya, I think you should do it in advance, so when your user comes, tags are all ready.

Comment: It was really useful, but I would still want others to look into it, in case there is a better way, like database, or Sets(easier for intersections, unions)